# facebook logout url not working

Tags: facebook

https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next="mypage"&access_token="mytoken"

when I navigate above url from browser, the browser does not redirected to my redirect url but

redirect to facebook.com/home (it even not log user out).

I am not sure what am I doing wrong..

for the parameter "next", which url should I address? Website with Facebook Login or app domains?

and... this redirect url should be encoded like www%3Fmysite%3Fcom ??

I tried all of those and still cant log user out.. anyone tried logout with url??

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i forgot to mention that I dont use php sdk.

Answer (score 4):

Never mind. My url was wrong.

it should be `next=http://www.mysite.com/&access_token=token`

Comment: @DaveClemmer The OP wrote this answer. Many self-answers aren't answers, but this one is.

Comment: Sorry to ressurrect this, but where is the URL and parameters documented in FB site?